# if (a) {} throws uncaughtReferenceError

Tags: javascript, null, referenceerror

I need to be able to check if a variable exists (if if it doesn't assign it to {}) without throwing an error in javascript.  When I try this code

```
if (a) {}
```

it throws uncaughtReferenceError

What I really want to do is something like this without throwing an error:

```
a = a || {}
```

or maybe it looks like this

```
if (a) { a = {} }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `a = a || {} `?

Comment: @Kenneth That's still *get*-first, so same error. `a` won't be defined, if it isn't already, until after `a || {}` is evaluated.

Comment: Oh, I thaught you had it at least declared. In that case the answers below work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof a === 'undefined'){
  // variable is not available and you can write a = {}
}
```

but `a = a || {}` is shortly

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is a global, you can use the *global object* to avoid the error. In browsers, that object is `window`:

```
window.a = window.a || {};
```

Or, as Ozerich suggested, you can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), which won't throw reference errors:

```
if (typeof a === 'undefined') {
    a = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a || {}
```

simply won't work, because `a` is not defined. But you can use `typeof` to check if it exists or not.

```
a = (typeof(a) === 'undefined' ? {} : a);
```